# Get user name and surname by user id FB Api

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

In the Facebook API is there a way in which I can get a user's name and surname by user id?

I am using FB API in my ASP.NET MVC application and I am using the MultiFriendSelector to let the users invite friends to my app. I need that when these friends are selected, they are saved in my database so that they can have access to my pages. This is the code I have until now.

```
    function sendRequestToRecipients() {
        var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;

        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Join my group on CodeShare!',
            to: user_ids
        }, requestCallback);
    }

    function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Join my group on CodeShare!'
        }, requestCallback);
    }

    function requestCallback(response) {
        if (response.request && response.to) {
            var request_ids = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < response.to.length; i++) {
                var fb_id = response.to[i];
                request_ids.push(fb_id);

                //// here I want to get the user's names and
                     surnames so that I can send them along with the id's..

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Groups/SaveInvitedFriends',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { invitedFriends: request_ids }
                }); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way maybe in which the user's are saved upon accepting the request?

Thanks

Comment: no, that's would be too obvious ... LoL

Comment: hahaha my bad sorry! am a bit tired right now and have an assignment till 2 days! was a mistake.. I need name and surname!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to make an API call to request the user's info. Facebook's JavaScript API docs gives the following example:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
});
```

(from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#graphapi)

`me` refers to the currently logged in user. If you use a userid instead, the `response` object will contain `name`(full name), `first_name`, `last_name` (surname), and several other basic fields. For example, `zuck` is the userid of Mark Zuckerberg, so using the request `FB.api("/zuck", function(response) { console.log(response); });` returns the following:

```
Object {
    first_name: "Mark"
    gender: "male"
    id: "4"
    last_name: "Zuckerberg"
    link: "https://www.facebook.com/zuck"
    locale: "en_US"
    name: "Mark Zuckerberg"
    updated_time: "2013-05-09T05:12:23+0000"
    username: "zuck"
}
```

Let me know if this makes sense or if you have any questions :)